# Реализация класса c#

Tags: c#

Имеется 3 формы, на каждой по Chart.

Логично написать класс, реализующий функционал настройки данных Chart и рисования на них. Проблема в том, что из методов класса естественно не видно контролов форм(private всё-таки). Настройка и рисование сопровождаются довольно большим набором условий, которые для всех трёх форм абсолютно разные... В том числе и по типам и количеству проверяемых/принимаемых значений.

Вопрос в следующем: как наиболее правильно реализовать методы работы с Chart:

1. Внешним классом с передачей нужного Chart непосредственно в метод.
2. Классом для Chart с интерфейсом (соответственно будет 3 объекта,только не очень понятно как их отличать).
3. Как-то ещё...

Есть подозрение, что вопрос глуп и ответ на него элементарен, но прозрения пока не приходит.

---

Пока остановился на варианте:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            Drawer drawer;
            internal class Drawer : DrawClass
            {
                Form1 _form;
                public Drawer(Form1 form)
                {
                    _form = form;
                }

                protected override void func()
                {
                    _form.label1.Text = "12345";
                }
            }

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                drawer = new Drawer(this);
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               drawer.MainFunc();
            }
        }
```

Общий класс для всех форм, в нем и будут определены все нужные методы и в его объект передана ссылка на нужный Chart, где рисовать.

```
    abstract internal class DrawClass
    {
        abstract protected void func();
        public void MainFunc()
        {
            func();
        }
    }
```

drawer - тот, кто рисует, наследуется от класса DrawClass, в котором хранятся и вызываются все необходимые методы для настройки и рисования (в главном методе MainFunc).
func - переопределенная функция абстрактного класса, которая будет различна для каждой формы (и привязанного к ней класса Drawer).
Приходится передавать в конструктор класса ссылку на текущую форму, чтобы получать доступ к контролам (label).
Имеет ли сие творение право на жизнь или выкинуть, забыть и face-vs-table?

Comment: Вопрос совершенно не глупый, о том как надо разделять сущности и их взаимодействие, возможное использование паттернов, нигде не пишут, а если и пишут то общие слова или "научными" словами, все приходит с опытом.

Comment: Если можно, распишите по подробнее. В частности, правильно ли я понял, что на всех трех формах разный набор полей для ввода начальных данных? Есть пересечение таких полей? Или все начальные данные выбираются автоматически?

Comment: Набор полей разный абсолютно и по кол-во и по типам данных.

Comment: Вот как раз потому что не пишут и хотелось услышать мнение тех,у кого данный опыт имеется - как лучше,как проще на взгляд знающего.

Comment: Попытаюсь подробнее. 3 формы, 3 чарта, 3 набора полей. По некоему событию (допустим, нажали кнопку, не важно, но каждое событие исходит от своей формы) необходимо настроить чарт в зависимости от того,что в наборе полей и вывести некий график из этих данных. Проблема в том, чтобы оформить код настройки и вывода графика, чтобы не пришлось в каждой форме определять эти однотипные методы.

Comment: Приведите примитивный пример вашей задачи без отдельного класса настройки. Так можно будет наглядно увидеть связующие и/или повторяющиеся участки кода и уже понять как это упростить. Честно, я пока никак не могу понять что конкретно должно объединять 3 разных Chart с разными полями и разными данными =/

Comment: Легко. Форма 1. 4 текстовых поля задают координаты 2-х точек, по которым строится график. Форма 2. Выпадающие списки с наборами данных для тех же 2 точек. Форма 3. Таблица, в которой напрямую не содержится этих точек, но их можно получить из БД по какому-либо ключу.